# Searching a method like getResourcesID(int)

Tags: java, android

I'm searching a method that gives me the ID (int) from the Resource from a ImageView in my App. I don't know the name of the Image or something else. i only have an imageview and there is an Image from my Resources inside.

The reason is that i need it is to save it in my SQLite Database as an Integer.
Because later i will read this Data in my SQLite Database to use the method
`ImageView.setImageResource((int) R.drawable.SavedPic)`.

I'm only a beginner in programming so it will not be the best way to do it but i coding the hole day and i hope that you can give me the right method.

Comment: `R.drawable.SavedPic` is already an integer. I don't see why you're casting it to an integer, and I don't see the issue here.

Comment: You should provide some information, and code you've worked on to get help.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to get the `Image Resource Id` from an `ImageView`. But there is a way to hold onto that using `tags`. So if you have an `ImageView` called `imageView` and an image resource called `R.drawable.image` you can do something like this:

```
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image);
imageView.setTag(R.drawable.image);
```

And later when you want to get the resource Id associated with the `ImageView` you can fetch it using

```
int imageResourceId = (Integer) imageView.getTag();
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer !